# Motivation for tensor density

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, general-relativity

Wiki has provided the basic definitions of the tensor density, but what I really want to know is the motivation and the advantage of this concept. Could anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: The examples in the end of the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) provide enough motivation for the notion of tensor densities, don't they?

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thanks for your time, I am so sorry to ask this stupid question to waste your time. I am too rush to miss this important information.

Comment: This is not a stupid question at all. I was just curious how much motivation would you need? We all are here to ask and answer questions. Will my comment do, or do you still want a more detailed answer?

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Yes, if there are still more motivations, I would love to know the details. Actually, I am reading some papers on mathematical general relativity. Several authors always use $\sqrt{g}$ to resale tensors, this is why I found this concept "tensor density". I want to know these authors' motivation from the motivations of tensor density. Many thanks for your attention.